# Why my GoogleLogIn cannot automatically jump to “settings View”？iOS SwuifUI

Tags: swiftui, firebase-authentication

I'm using SwiftUI create a Google sign in button and it should automatically jump to my "SettingsView". However, it's not working and without alert. The console did print out "signed in successful!", I have no idea where is the issued and how to fix it.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
extension AuthenticationManager {

// Sign in with Google credentials
@discardableResult
func signInWithGoogle(tokens: GoogleSignInResultModel) async throws -> AuthDataResultModel {
    
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: tokens.idToken, accessToken: tokens.accessToken)
    return try await signIn(credential: credential)
}

// Sign in with a generic credential
   func signIn(credential: AuthCredential) async throws ->   AuthDataResultModel {
    
     let authDataResult = try await   Auth.auth().signIn(with:credential)
     return AuthDataResultModel(user: authDataResult.user)
  }

}


@MainActor final class AuthenticationViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var googleIsLoggedIn = false

// Sign in with Google using Google Sign-In
func signInGoogle() async throws {
    
    guard let topVC = Utilities.shared.topViewController() else {
        throw URLError(.cannotFindHost)
    }
    
    let gidSignInResult = try await GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: topVC)
    
    
    guard let idToken = gidSignInResult.user.idToken?.tokenString else {
        throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
    }
    
    let accessToken = gidSignInResult.user.accessToken.tokenString
    
    let tokens = GoogleSignInResultModel(idToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)
    
    // Sign in with Google credentials
    try await AuthenticationManager.shared.signInWithGoogle(tokens: tokens)
    googleIsLoggedIn = true
    
  }
}


GoogleSignInButton(viewModel: GoogleSignInButtonViewModel(scheme: .dark, style: .wide, state: .normal)) {
                Task {
                    do {
                        // Sign in with Google
                        try await viewModel.signInGoogle()
                        
                        viewModel.googleIsLoggedIn = true
                        
                        showSignInView = false
                        print("signed in successful!")
                        
                    } catch {
                        print("Google Sign-In Error: \(error)")
                    }
                }
                
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationTitle("Sign In")
        }
        NavigationLink(
            destination: settingsView(showSignInView: $showSignInView),
            isActive: $viewModel.googleIsLoggedIn,
            label: { EmptyView() }
        )
```

Anyone knows where is the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: There's not enough info here to represent the problem. We have no idea where `viewModel` is stored or what the lifespan of it is. For instance, you may be using `@ObservedObject` instead of `@StateObject`. Can you organize your code so we can see them as separate files/views with all the info we need rather than in one text block where different constructs are mixed together?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.